# jquery wrap the checkbox and label in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created one wordpress plugin to create contact form.. if i create multiple checkbox it looks like below code:

```
<input class="newch" name="chkbox[]" value="Product Specifcation" type="checkbox">
 Product Specifcation<br>

 <input class="newch" name="chkbox[]" value="Country Of origin" type="checkbox">
 Country Of origin<br>

 <input class="newch" name="chkbox[]" value="Minimum Order quantity" type="checkbox">
 Minimum Order quantity<br>

 <input class="newch" name="chkbox[]" value="Prouduct Warranty" type="checkbox">
 Prouduct Warranty<br>

 <input class="newch" name="chkbox[]" value="Unit Price" type="checkbox">
  Unit Price<br>
```

now i want to wrap  each checkbox and it's label to a div for **ex**

```
  <div class="chk-bx">
 <input class="newch" name="chkbox[]" value="Unit Price" type="checkbox">
  Unit Price<br>
  </div>


  <div class="chk-bx">
 <input class="newch" name="chkbox[]" value="Prouduct Warranty" type="checkbox">
 Prouduct Warranty<br>
  </div>


 <div class="chk-bx">
 <input class="newch" name="chkbox[]" value="Country Of origin" type="checkbox">
 Country Of origin<br>

  </div>
```

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.newch').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.add(this.nextSibling).add($this.next()).wrapAll('<div class="chk-bx"/>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sWnmV/)